# como concatenar fechas(smalldatetime)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

tengo la siguiente función :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F_FECHA_ABONOS] (@id_articulo int)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ts VARCHAR

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT    @ts =ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR, recibo_abonos.fecha  , 103), 0)
    FROM    dbo.recibo_abonos
    where(recibo_abonos.id_articulo = @id_articulo)  and (recibo_abonos.TipoRecibo = 8)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ts
END
```

y quiero ver como concatenar las fechas en la variable @ts.
De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Tu campo @ts es una cadena, solo es cuestión de concatener con `+`, algo asi `ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR, recibo_abonos.fecha  , 103), 0) + ' '  + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR, recibo_abonos.fecha2  , 103), 0)`

Comment: pero si mi select jala N fechas como las concateno ?

Comment: Obtiene una fecha, pero la convierte a varchar en formato 103, que corresponde a DD/MM/YYYY, por eso únicamente agrega el + y concatena tu otra fecha, igual parseada a varchar

Answer (score 0):

Para formar una lista separada por comas con todas las fechas, puedes valerte de la *construcción* `for xml path`, que te devolverá la concatenación de los valores. Con la función `stuff` eliminamos la primera coma, que está de más: así:

```
declare @ts varchar(max);

select @ts = STUFF((
                select ',' + convert(varchar, recibo_abonos.fecha  , 103)
                  from dbo.recibo_abonos
                   for XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 1, '')

select @ts;
```